# Is the R help-file for `<<-` in fact correct?

Tags: r, scope

I am trying to explain scoping and debugging for a presentation on R. I was reading the helpfile for `<<-` and saw it says this:

> The operators <<- and ->> are normally only used in functions, and
>   cause a search to be made through parent environments for an existing
>   definition of the variable being assigned. If such a variable is found
>   (and its binding is not locked) then its value is redefined, otherwise
>   assignment takes place in the global environment.

But I don't think that quite describes what `<<-` does. Here is a function:

```
do.func <- function() {
  x <- 1
  {
    x<<-0
  }
  print(x)
}

do.func()
x
```

produces this output:

```
>     do.func()
[1] 1
>     x
[1] 0
```

It seems that what `<<-` does is go straight to the global environment. Is this correct?

Comment: The `{}` block doesn't create a new environment. All the commands in your function are in the same environment. You need a sub-function (or create an explicit environment object) to get a new environment. The help file is correct.

Comment: You can verify what @MrFlick says by putting `print(environment())` in the function definition, both inside and outside the brackets.

Comment: @JohnColeman I tried it and I get the same environment twice. I don't quite know what that is telling me. Basically that `{` alone doesn't do anything except enclose a set of expressions?

Comment: `do.func2 <- function() {
  x <- 1
  {
    child.func <- function(){
      x <<- 0
    }
    child.func()
  }
  print(x)
}

;do.func2()`

Comment: @AdamO `{` is a function. What you are doing in fact is calling `\`{\`(x <<-0)` which is evaluated before being passed to `{`. Also see `help(\`{\`)`

Comment: @user This is helpful. However, this assigns an `x` in the global environment for me. I thought it would only overwrite the `x` that lives inside the scope of `do.func2`. It looks like `<<-` is assigning/reassigning "x" that lives in *every* parent environment.

Comment: The fact that you get the same environment twice is the point. Your question was predicated upon `{}` creating a new environment (which, if true, would have led to different things being printed).

Comment: No it doesn't, try removing the `x` in your global environment with `rm(x)` and run my code again.

Comment: @user oh thanks, my mistake. This operates exactly as I expected based on the helpfile. I had two misunderstandings that I figured out with your and MrFlick's.

Comment: Missed some semi-colons in the inline version. Try this instead: `do.func2 <- function() { x <- 1; { child.func <- function(){ x <<- 0 } ;child.func() }; print(x) } ;do.func2()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one attempt to make the situation more clear.

The function can be rewritten in this way:

```
do.func <- function() {
  `<-`(x, 1)
  `{`(x <<- 0)
  print(x)
}
```

Having it spelled out like that (only function calls) makes it clear what is going on. The part inside the `{` block in particular is composed of two functions:

```
`{` (`<<-`(x, 0) )
```

The function within:

```
`<<-`(variable, value)
```

Assigns the value to the variable and returns invisibly. For example:

```
> ( `<<-`(x, 2) )
[1] 2
```

Therefore - it is being evaluated in the same environment where the x is (in your example). So what is going on in this block:

```
{
  x<<-0
}
```

First x is overwritten and only after that the value of x is passed to the function `{` which simply returns the last expression.

See also:

```
help(`{`)
```

Comment: Nicely summarized. I guess one thing I learned that's worth adding/making explicit is that `<<-` *strictly* looks in (the) parent environment(s) for assignment/reassignment. I would have expected the output of: `do.func <- function() {x <- 0; x <<- 1; print(x)}` to print 1 but it prints 0 and assigns 1 to x in the `GlobalEnv.`.

Comment: Yup, my "answer" only tries to explain why the expression inside `{` `}` block is not a separate environment. I agree with you that the help for `<<-` could make it more explicit about it starting search at parent environment and not current.